# Order a list of words in one column of R

Tags: r, apply, sapply, arules

I have the output data frame from apriori, the rules as given below:

```
rules
{A,B} => {C}
{C,A} => {B}
{A,B} => {D}
{A,D} => {B}
{A,B} => {E}
{E,A} => {B}
```

I got it till this point where I grouped the items in each rule (data.frame is df_basket)

```
rules           basket
{A,B} => {C}    A,B,C
{C,A} => {B}    C,A,B
{A,B} => {D}    A,B,D
{A,D} => {B}    A,D,B
{A,B} => {E}    A,B,E
{E,A} => {B}    E,A,B
```

I want to be able to order the basket in alphabetical order as given below:

```
rules           basket  Group
{A,B} => {C}    A,B,C   A,B,C
{C,A} => {B}    C,A,B   A,B,C
{A,B} => {D}    A,B,D   A,B,D
{A,D} => {B}    A,D,B   A,B,D
{A,B} => {E}    A,B,E   A,B,E
{E,A} => {B}    E,A,B   A,B,E
```

I used the code below which works fine for small data frames and gets the job done. The for loop is inefficient for large data frames. Please help me in optimizing this atomic operation in R:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df_basket))
{
  df_basket$Basket[i]<- ifelse(1==1,paste(unlist(strsplit(df_basket$basket[i],","))
                                          [order(unlist(strsplit(df_basket$basket[i],",")))],collapse=","))

}
```

Please let me know if there is anything easy or more direct to get the "Group" field of my data frame.

Comment: Please provide your input data in a reproducible form, for instance using `dput(head(df_basket))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to adapt this solution:

```
f<-function(x)
{
  sorted<-sort(unlist(strsplit(x,",")))
  return(paste0(sorted,collapse = ","))

}
cbind(basket,unlist(lapply(basket,f)))
```

Input data:

```
basket<-c("A,B,C","C,A,B","A,B,D","A,D,B","A,B,E","E,A,B")
```

Output:

```
     basket         
[1,] "A,B,C" "A,B,C"
[2,] "C,A,B" "A,B,C"
[3,] "A,B,D" "A,B,D"
[4,] "A,D,B" "A,B,D"
[5,] "A,B,E" "A,B,E"
[6,] "E,A,B" "A,B,E"
```

Comment: Yes! This works. Thanks. I have tested it on 10K and it works much faster than the for loop. I am trying it now on 3M and it is taking some time.

Comment: You are welcome, lapply is better then a for loop, but with 3M rows it will take some minutes.

Comment: It took less than 5 minutes, and is definitely a much better alternative than the for loop. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using more support from `arules`:

```
### create some random data and mine rules
library("arules")
dat <- replicate(10, sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 3), simplify = FALSE)
trans <- as(dat, "transactions")
rules <- apriori(trans)
inspect(rules)

    lhs      rhs support confidence lift     count
[1] {}    => {A} 0.8     0.8        1.000000 8    
[2] {B}   => {A} 0.6     1.0        1.250000 6    
[3] {C,D} => {E} 0.2     1.0        1.428571 2    
[4] {B,D} => {A} 0.1     1.0        1.250000 1    
[5] {B,C} => {A} 0.2     1.0        1.250000 2    
[6] {B,E} => {A} 0.3     1.0        1.250000 3   

### Get the itemsets that generated each rule and convert the itemsets 
### into a list. I use a list, since in gerneral, rules will not all 
### have the same number of items.
itemsets <- as(items(generatingItemsets(rules)), "list")

### sort the item labels alphabetically. Note that you could already 
### start with the item labels correctly sorted in the transaction set
### (see manual page for itemcoding in arules).
lapply(itemsets, sort)

[[1]]
[1] "A"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[3]]
[1] "C" "D" "E"

[[4]]
[1] "A" "B" "D"

[[5]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

[[6]]
[1] "A" "B" "E"
```

If all rules have the same number of items then you can drop this list into a matrix.

If you want them as a single string then you can do:

```
sapply(lapply(itemsets, sort), paste0, collapse = ",")
[1] "A"     "A,B"   "C,D,E" "A,B,D" "A,B,C" "A,B,E"
```